# Satellizer causes Angular to pre-flight ALL of my rest queries with an OPTIONS request

Tags: angularjs, preflight, satellizer

If all servers responded to an OPTIONS request this would not be a problem, but Satellizer even causes Angular to pre-flight a GET request with Content-Type text/plain. In effect, it breaks half of my other REST queries.

Comment: preflight happens when the request is not a simple request (includes extra headers, cookies, etc.) The Authorization header causes it to need a preflight. So, make it not send said extra headers and it'l stop sending a pre-flight. Sounds like you have an interceptor that isn't filtering to only specific domains, and is instead applying the auth header to everything.

Comment: After reading through docs, looks like you'll have to disable the built-in interceptor and implement your own.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you are absolutely right. Satellizer implements httpInterceptor which is intercepting every single request. I found a workaround, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the code and studying Angualr's httpProvider I realized that Sateliizer is intercepting every single request using httpProvider's interceptors array and adding the following:

```
var token = localStorage.getItem(tokenName);
if (token && config.httpInterceptor) {
  token = config.authHeader === 'Authorization' ? 'Bearer ' + token : token;
  httpConfig.headers[config.authHeader] = token;
}
```

So that every single request gets an Authorization header. Since I actually have only ONE request that needs an authorization header I modified the conditional statement:

```
if (token && config.httpInterceptor && httpConfig.auth===true) {
```

and then in my $http.get for the single service that actually needs authorization I add:

```
        var config = {auth: true};
        $http.get(googleUrl, config)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `satellizer` library for managing authorization.  Since I also make REST calls to third party APIs, I don't want to include the `Authorization` header. Adding `skipAuthorization:true` in the configuration block solved my issue.  For example:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('weather')
    .factory('weatherResource', ['$http', function ($http) {
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Bangalore&appid=a50e83454ba54b9',
        skipAuthorization: true
      });
    }]);
})();
```

Good luck.